# How to use object notation to build a new object with JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, object, higher-order-functions

This is the solution code from an exercise within the "Eloquent JavaScript" book. This is code is from chapter 5 and it is exercise 2.

I know `byName` object is being built by using the `forEach` method. I understand this. However, the object bracket notation is hard to understand because I do not know how the local variable `person` is being used.

Within the variable `differences` the `filter` method and the `map` method is being used and i understand how they are being used. However I do not know the value of the local variable `person` and I do not know how the `byName` object is being used.

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

var byName = {};
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  byName[person.name] = person;
});

var differences = ancestry.filter(function(person) {
  return byName[person.mother] != null;
}).map(function(person) {
  return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
});

console.log(average(differences));
// 31.2
```

How is the `byName` object being incorporated in the `filter` method and the `forEach` method? What is the value of the local variable `person` within the `filter` method and the `forEach` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Array of Objects (`ancestry`) each object representing a `Person`. Person has a property called mother that has his/her mother's name (which is a string).

In order to go from a person's mother's name to the actual Person Object that represents the mother you need to create a map that has keys being person's name and value being person object (byName, created in the forEach) .

The filter function returns a new Array that holds only the people that actually have a valid mother (there is a mother object in the byName registry for that name). Using that new list [of valid person/mother] objects we compute the age difference for all of them (the map function) by taking the persons born property and subtracting the mothers born property (`byname[person.mother].born`)

I hope this doesn't make things more complicated..

---

The code assumes that ancestry is an array of objects with this structure:

```
[{
  name: 'John Doe'
  born: 2,
  mother: 'Jane Doe'
},
{
  name: 'Jane Doe'
  born: 1,
  mother: null
}]
```

And after the forEach has run `byName` will be:

```
{
  'John Doe': {
    name: 'John Doe',
    born: 2,
    mother: 'Jane Doe'
  },
  'Jane Doe': {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    born: 1,
    mother: null,
  }
}
```

The Filter returns a new list:

```
[{
  name: 'John Doe',
  born: 2,
  mother: 'Jane Doe'
}]
```

Note how it got rid of `Jane Doe` because the mother property wasn't valid.

The map function will loop through the new Array returned from filter with only one item 'John Doe' and `person.mother` has the value 'Jane Doe' and `byName` has a property `Jane Doe` so `byName[person.mother]` will return the:

```
{
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  born: 1,
  mother: null
}
```

Comment: Your first and third paragraphs were helpful. However, I need clarification on your second paragraph. Am I on the right track when I say the 'forEach' method is creating a connection that states "jane doe" is the mother of "john doe"? If so, how is this being done? The syntax 'byName[person.name] = person;' is still confusing me.